# Can I prevent logback's DBAppender from logging specific properties?

Tags: java, logback

Logback's DBAppender logs all properties in its context and MDC to the database. I would like to control which properties are logged, specifically filtering out certain values, but I can't find any options to do so. The documentation is terse:

> The logging_event_property is used to store the keys and values contained in the MDC or the Context

Is it possible to exclude certain properties from being logged?

Here is an example:

Logback is configured with a `DBAppender` that loads its properties from `vct.properties`:

```
<configuration>
    <property resource="vct.properties" />

    <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DataSourceConnectionSource">
            <dataSource class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
                <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
                <jdbcUrl>jdbc:mysql://${log.db.host}:${log.db.port}/${log.db.schema}</jdbcUrl>
                <user>${log.db.username}</user>
                <password>${log.db.password}</password>
            </dataSource>
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="DB" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

`vct.properties` has the connection settings:

```
log.db.host=localhost
log.db.port=3306
log.db.schema=logs_development
log.db.username=loguser
log.db.password=logpass
```

When an event is logged, all of the connection settings are logged:

```
mysql> select * from logging_event_property where event_id=1;
+----------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| event_id | mapped_key          | mapped_value                              |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|        1 | log.db.host         | localhost                                 | 
|        1 | log.db.password     | logpass                                   | 
|        1 | log.db.port         | 3306                                      | 
|        1 | log.db.schema       | logs_development                          | 
|        1 | log.db.username     | loguser                                   | 
+----------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logback does not currently support this feature. If you haven't already please enter a bug report requesting this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Was stumbling over a kinda similar error these days as well. In my case I imported the properties via

```
<springProperty ...>
```

definition. When the scope of the springProperty is set to "context" it will be automatically added to the "logging_event_property" table. By removing the scope (default is local) the springProperties aren't added anymore :-)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to filtering which entries are added to the database, I wrote a Java program to list the logback dbappender database to the console which also supports filtering.

https://github.com/Rockvole/db_logviewer